# How to programmatically get info about storage drives in linux? (C# MONO)

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, storage

I need programmatically get all storage drives available in a linux system with the following fields:

- Path
- File System (FAT32, NTFS, etc)
- Containing Physical Disk

It need to support all common storage types: hard disks, Disk-On-Keys, CdRom, Dvd, etc.

How to do this from C# to run well from MONO?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite simple.
Read the contents of the folder /dev/disk/by-path.
The files in this directory are symbolic links to device files in /dev.
then you can find some general info about those, using a mono port of gudev - you can get one [here](https://code.launchpad.net/gudev-sharp).
you also need glib-sharp to use this, it is part of the gtk-sharp2 package (install that using your package manager). 
use as in this example:

```
GLib.GType.Init();
gudev.GUdevClient a=new gudev.GUdevClient(null);            
gudev.GUdevDevice dev=a.QueryByDeviceFile("/dev/disk/by-path/--some-file--");
Console.WriteLine (dev.GetProperty("ID_FS_TYPE")); //will output the file system, eg. ntfs
Console.WrtieLine(dev.GetProperty("ID_FS_LABEL")); //will output the label of the disk
```

to get the mountpoint, you should find the actual device file.
add a reference to the package "Mono.Posix" and use the Mono.Unix.UnixSymbolicLinkInfo class to find that file.
for example:

```
Mono.Unix.UnixSymbolicLinkInfo sym=new Mono.Unix.UnixSymbolicLinkInfo("/dev/disk/by-path/--some-file--");
Console.WriteLine(sym.ContentsPath); //Will output something like ../../sda1
```

replace the ../.. with /dev and than read the file /etc/mtab.
the format of the file is something like this:

> ```
> /dev/file mountpoint stuff-you-don't-care-about
> ```

Each device in a new line. so split by /n and split that by space. anything after that is simple and i don't think i need to continue.

Comment: Just a remark: `"ID_FS_LABEL"` (and the associated `"ID_FS_LABEL_ENC"`) are only present if they were defined at the moment of disk creation. I have a bunch of old DVDs without disk labels - probably the software at that time didn't ask for it... Don't blame `gudev` ;)